# Deleting the last section of a UITableView causes an exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'

Below is the code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    @try {
        NSMutableArray *arrData = [dictStartDate* objectForKey:self.navigationItem.title];
        NSLog(@"Title : %@", self.navigationItem.title);
        NSLog(@"Array count : %i", (int)arrData.count);
        return arrData.count;
    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {
        [[ProjectHandler sharedHandler]LogException:ex.name description:ex.description className:@"TodayTasksViewController" functionName:@"numberOfRowsInSection"];
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: so little infomation.I guess you just delete last cell of the section and your numberofsections method return count is less than before because of your code.May be you can show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and I solved it testing if I am deleting the last row of a section, and if so instead of deleting the row, I deleted the section. I am returning 0 to the numberOfSectionsInTableView and there is no problem, the tableView is just empty.

Bellow follows the swift code I used to check if it is the last row of a section or not and the key part, which is to delete the section and not the row.

Suppose you have objects for sections in a table view like this:

```
var objects: [[Object]]?
```

Then if you are removing a row of this table with this objects you should do:

```
objects![indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
if (objects![indexPath.section].count == 0) {
    objects!.removeAtIndex(indexPath.section)
    tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .Left)
    return //End the func and not execute the next step
}

tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
```

Also you could use something like this to identify if it's the last row in a section:

```
tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be deleting the only section in the table. A table must have at least 1 section. You might want to check your code to check that you are not returning 0 in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

Comment: this isn't correct. See docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview

Comment: > a table is made up of zero or more sections