# No data view in tableView using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` in my tableview, and it works fine. My problem is, I want to create "no data view" when my `_fetchedResultsController` has 0 row.

I tried to create it in my `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if ([[_fetchedResultController.sections firstObject] numberOfObjects] == 0) {
        MyNoDataView *view = [[MyNoDataView alloc] initWithFrame:tableView.frame];
        tableView.backgroundView = view;
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        return  1;  
    }
}
```

It worked great. If there are no data inserted yet, it showed no data view and if there are datas it will show my tableview.

My problem starts when I made delete action on its row. Technically, I just update its object properties (`isActive`) as my `fetchRequest` in `fetchedResultController` using this `NSPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isActive == %@ ", @YES];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Then, if there is only 1 row, and I delete it, I get this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'
```

So I tried to remove my `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, and suddenly those error is gone. I have no idea what's going on here, but I think there is a mistake around my conditional on `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check the duplicate. You need to handle this in the NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods. The NSFetchedResultsController "doesn't know" if you are adding custom cells and sections. It just provides it's own data, and inserts cells and sections from its own account, and if you already have cells and sections, then the numbers don't add upp correctly, and you will crash. Also, **sidenote** Why do you even allocate "MyNoDataView" and setting seperatorstyles in numberOfSectionsInTableView ? That is really really bad practice.

Comment: **EDIT** I deleted the duplicate flag. Provide more code on how you handle the insertions and deletions etc. So we can locate the error easier. Maybe this can help you searching for the error code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951169/deleting-the-last-section-of-a-uitableview-causes-an-exception and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9964

Comment: I just want to create no data view tbh. So how do you think I should allocate my MyNoDataView and place it as tableview background? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just edited my comment added two links that provide solutions for your error code. However, presenting a "empty data" view is not as straightforward as it should be when you use NSFetchedResultscontroller and its delegate methods, you are basically smoked if you never done it before, it will take some time to get a grip around it. You need to handle the insertions and deletions manually in the NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods. The easiest way is to provide all the check in the delegate methods and tableView.reloadData when you want to switch between empty-content .

Comment: Thank you for your link. It helped me alot for learning this core data concept. But your second opinion make me think that could I presenting "empty data" in my controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType: delegate? I mean, every update I make, I checked if there's any data or not so I can create no data view?

Comment: Exactly. You could even provide an EmptyDataCell , and return the empty cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath when the fetched is empty. And in your controller.delegate methods you only need to reloadData when you swap between empty to content or content to empty. Otherwise you let the delegate methods run as normal :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much! Now I'll try to modified its delegate. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Based [Sneak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5890979/sneak)'s answer, allocating "MyNoDataView" and setting seperatorstyles in numberOfSectionsInTableView is really really bad practice. So I ended up with modifying my `controllerDidChangeContent:` on fetched result controller delegate

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    if ([controller.fetchedObjects count]) {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    else {
        MyDataView *view = [[MyDataView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = view;
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. I was also having a problem of similar nature. Fixed it now.

Comment: @sweta.me glad to hear that!